# Why does archive.extracted returns error eventhough a extract happened?

Tags: salt-stack

TAR extraction doesn't happen as expected with the below:

```
unpack_batch_tar:
archive.extracted:
  - name: /aaa/bbb/ccc
  - source: http://artifactory-dev/tarstuff/test.tar
  - keep_source: False
  - archive_format: tar
  - skip_verify: True
  - overwrite: True
```

Error reported:

```
----------
      ID: unpack_batch_tar
Function: archive.extracted
    Name: /aaa/bbb/ccc
  Result: False
 Comment: Archive does not have a single top-level directory. To allow this archive to be extracted, set 'enforce_toplevel' to False. To avoid a 'tar-bomb' it may also be advisable to set a top-level directory by adding it to the 'name' value (for example, setting 'name' to /aaa/bbb/ccc/some_dir instead of /aaa/bbb/ccc/).
 Started: 05:13:16.376999
Duration: 13.497 ms
```

### Changes:

To overcome this issue I added:

```
- enforce_toplevel: False
```

And created a subdirectory /aaa/bbb/ccc/some_dir but the extract don't happen. Below error is reported:

```
Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
            File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/state.py\", line 1750, in call
              **cdata['kwargs'])
            File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/loader.py\", line 1705, in wrapper
              return f(*args, **kwargs)
            File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/states/archive.py\", line 1252, in extracted
              tar.extractall(name)
            File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tarfile.py\", line 2047, in extractall
              self.extract(tarinfo, path)
            File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tarfile.py\", line 2084, in extract
              self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name))
            File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tarfile.py\", line 2168, in _extract_member
              self.makelink(tarinfo, targetpath)
            File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tarfile.py\", line 2252, in makelink
              os.link(tarinfo._link_target, targetpath)
          OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't see an indentation issue as the same works good for .JAR file but fails for a .TAR file. I am not sure why only a TAR extract fails.

Comment: Please show us your code so we can help you

Comment: If your unpack code is *exactly* the one in the question, you have an indentation error

Comment: daks, the exact script works fine for a JAR extract and I see an issue with TAR. I don't think an indentation error, I had made changes to above just to post the question in the site.